# Is there an equivalent to static of C in C#?

Tags: c#, c, static

In C I can do

```
void foo() {
  static int c = 0;
  printf("%d,", c);
  c ++;
}

foo(); 
foo(); 
foo();
foo();
```

it should print `0,1,2,3`

Is there an equivalent  in C#?

Comment: But I want to do exactly how in above code C. It's possible?

Comment: no you can't have local static variables in C#.  Having a class variable is as close as you can get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
class C
{
    private static int c = 0;
    public void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only "sort of", `c` is visible to all methods.

Comment: @pst I don't think there is a way of scoping static variables in c# without using an internal/external pattern.

Comment: @aleroot Of course it's not the same, as this kind of declaration simply doesn't exists in C#. This is the closest you'll get though.

Comment: Yes, but the question ask : Is there an equivalent to static of C in C#?  --- Answer : NO

Comment: I had to give the -1 for not *talking about* how this is *not the same* in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

While some have suggested as `static` *member* variable, this is not the same due to visibility. As an *alternative* to the answer by aquinas, if *closures are accepted*, then this can be done:

(Note that `Foo` is a a *property* and not a *method* and that `c` is "per instance".)

```
class F {
    public readonly Action Foo;
    public F () {
        int c = 0; // closured
        Foo = () => {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            c++;
        };
    }
}

var f = new F();
f.Foo();  // 0
f.Foo();  // 1
```

However, C# has *no direct* equivalent to a `static` variable in C.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no way to achieve the same behaviour as the static c function variable ...

Answer (score 2):

There are no globals in C#, however, you can create a static field within your class.

```
public class Foo{
    private static int c = 0;
    void Bar(){
       Console.WriteLine(c++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only "sort of", `c` is visible to all methods.

Comment: `WriteLine()` accpets `object` data type. You don't need convert it to string. Only do: `Console.WriteLine(c++);`

Comment: I think "member" or "field" is the word you are looking for, not "constant", as a) this isn't constant on purpose, and b) true constants are declared with `const` rather than `static`, as in `private static const int Zero = 0`.

Comment: @pst You cannot scope static fields to methods. This is the closest you'll get. By making the field private, you'll at least scope it to the current class.

Comment: @Ruben, you're right, I think I just had a brainfart.
@TheMask, I'm just used to `""+object` as an invocator of `toString()`.  Personal preference, I guess.

Comment: @pst: In C, the `c` variable is visible only in scope that was it declared.

Comment: I had to give the -1 for not *talking about* how this is *not the same* in the answer.

Comment: @Jack ..which is precisely why is is "sort of" an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it at a method level. The closest you can do at a method level is something like this, and this isn't really that close. In particular, it only works if you have a reference to the enumerator. If someone else calls this method, they won't see your changes.

```
   class Program {
        static IEnumerable<int> Foo() {
            int c = 0;
            while (true) {
                c++;
                yield return c;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var x = Foo().GetEnumerator();
            Console.WriteLine(x.Current); //0            
            x.MoveNext();
            Console.WriteLine(x.Current); //1
            x.MoveNext();
            Console.WriteLine(x.Current); //2
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

What interesting is that VB.NET does support static local variables: http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/pages/7717.aspx. As this page notes, .NET itself doesn't support this, but the VB.NET compiler fakes it by adding a static class level variable.

Comment: Yikes! Also note that this isn't really very global/static, as you'll need to keep track of the enumerator `x` all the time. A static field is much closer to a static variable in C, apart from the visibility, which is broader in C# for a static field than for a static variable in C.

Comment: I'm aware of that :). I don't know the entire reason why the OP wanted to do something like this, so I included this merely as something that he *may* want to look at. I guess I should delete before I get downvoted more. :)

Comment: If going down this route I'd rather use a "normal" closure, but an interesting approach... and since this doesn't say "use a static member", well, +1!